# Manage multiple linux users

Tags: linux, user-management

I have a homelab there is growing larger and larger and I am learning more and more every day. I was wondering if it is possible to manage all of my users from one server? So i don't have to create a new root and normal user with sudo access each time i spin up another Vm? and easily create a new user, reset password and ect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage your users using a ldap server, look at freeipa: https://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of central user management techniques available in Linux: [ldap](/questions/tagged/ldap), [nis](/questions/tagged/nis), and [kerberos](/questions/tagged/kerberos) are the oldest and probably the best documented and debugged.  All of those are going to require a master-slave setup to maintain semi-reliably and replication can be arduous to configure.

Rather than pull your hair out that much when trying to simplify your life I'd suggest using [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible).  You can get started without creating any infrastructure other than ssh keys.  Ansible has a [user module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html) for managing users, but it also allows you to configure everything else.  Maybe you want to have all of your servers using the same name servers: add [a little more ansible](https://github.com/jdauphant/ansible-role-dns/blob/master/tasks/main.yml).  Maybe you want all of your servers to display a helpful `/etc/motd` then [ansible can help](https://github.com/fourkitchens/server-playbooks/blob/master/ubuntu-12.04-lamp-dev/setup.yml#L36) again.  The opportunities for saving yourself repeated work go on and on and go much further than keeping your users in sync.

Comment: Ansible is similair to puppet right? I all ready have a puppet serv. Running but i thougt it would be a great exercise to srtup somethibg like ldap

Comment: Yes, ansible is like puppet, but it doesn't require the central server.  If you're looking for something fun to setup, go for Kerberos.

Comment: puppet neither requires a central server, you can use it if you wish but it's just an option.
But i think we're getting OT here.

Comment: Fredi: you are correct, but that wasn't always so and most places I've been still use it as client-server.  Ansible is still easier to get going standalone.  Plus the whole question is OT since homelabs are probably not a professional context.  :)

Comment: it is defently not a professional but it is fun to see how close i can get to a professional enviroment

Answer (score 1):

using OpenLdap is a good idea... It's almost used everywhere and + you can even use ldap to:

- store your sudo configuration check what the documentation of sudo
  says about Sudoers ldap
  (http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.14/sudoers.ldap.man.ht

ml)

- store your openssh authorized_keys,for more information you can check this post: [SSH key authentication using LDAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/653792/ssh-key-authentication-using-ldap)

cheers,
Julian

Answer (score 0):

If your network is reasonably protected, using NIS is very simple to manage.  NIS itself isn't very secure, but the setup is not at all complicated.  I would also suggest exporting the home directories to all the other machines via nfs from the same server.

I've had several labs at work with the NIS/nfs setup and I can add, replace or upgrade machines and the users just log on like nothing ever changed - all their configs and files just show up no matter what machine they use.