# Multiple Linux servers login via keyring

Tags: linux, security, ldap, authentication

I have a number of Linux VM on the cloud as well as on in-house VM servers. They are a mix of RH, OEL, CentOS, Ubuntu.

As part of security hardening, I have disabled password authentication and all users login using public/private keys. To use this method, when I add a user to a VM, I copy his authorized_keys file. All of my users use Windows 10 and Putty clients.

So far so good.

I was wondering, is there a method whereby I could place all public key files in a central place such as a keyring? That way I wouldn't have to copy them to each server. Then the servers could read the public keys from there to authenticate users. How about LDAP? Can I put the public keys into LDAP entries?

Comment: There is [a post about SSH keys and LDAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/653792/ssh-key-authentication-using-ldap). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, @Lacek. Thank you.