# Better alternatives to standard SSH key management

Tags: ssh

Is there an open source or commercial product or service that can offer ssh login to linux servers without having to manually manage and deploy SSH keys, or at least to do it in more automated manner.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic

Comment: There are already lots and lots of questions about SSH key management on this site an several solutions are presented there.

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSH has little know feature called the [`AuthorizedKeysCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedKeysCommand) which allows you to configure your sshd daemon to run a specific help program to retrieve the public keys that you would normally store and deploy in a users `˜/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

That helper program can for example query a database server, a LDAP server or whatever else might be suitable for your purposes.

That avoids the common alternatives of using configuration management tooling to deploy keys to `˜/.ssh/authorized_keys` files or to mount network shares  with (administrator/user) home directories containing  `˜/.ssh/authorized_keys` files.

See this Q&A for an LDAP example: [SSH key authentication using LDAP](https://serverfault.com/q/653792/960939)