# ssh how to allow a very limited user with no home to login with pubkey

Tags: ssh, shell, ssh-keys, public-key

I have a very restricted user in my ssh server created with `--no-create-home` and `--shell /bin/false`.
I know I can define `authorized_keys` file in `sshd_configs` for the user's public key. But how can I allow public key authentication for this user without requiring to access any files on OS?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking for exactly. Does diya's answer solve your problem? What exactly do you want your restricted user to do after logging in?

Comment: @ciamej In my case this limited user is defined for tcp_forwarding (local ssh tunneling). I think diya's answer is useful for more complicated situations. I was thinking maybe a very simple command could be used or defined for a user to define known public keys, as simple as defining a password while creating a user.

Answer (score 15):

diya has [already explained](https://serverfault.com/a/1112593/245318) that you could change to `AuthorizedKeysCommand` for retrieving the public key of a user.

However, it's probably easier for you to place the authorized_keys file somewhere else. For example you could set `AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorizedkeys/%u` and place the file that would have been at `~username/.ssh/authorized_keys` at `/etc/ssh/authorizedkeys/username` instead.

And, if you want to change it only for this user (so other users still have their `authorized_keys` at `~/.ssh/`), you could use

```
Match User username
AuthorizedKeysFile /some/path/username_authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 11):

The alternative to a file with public keys  is the openssh server directive [`AuthorizedKeysCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedKeysCommand) which allows you to configure your sshd daemon to run a specific helper program to retrieve the public keys that you would normally store and deploy in a users `˜/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Using a LDAP directory is one common solution, querying an API or (MySQL) database are other examples.

See for example:

- [SSH key authentication using LDAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/653792)
- [How to enable ssh for supporters with intelligent key management?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1105280)
- [OpenSSH with public keys from database](https://serverfault.com/questions/162238)