# Is there a solution to manage users in some systems or at least in linux?

Tags: ssh-keys, user-management, user-accounts, single-sign-on

I work somewhere with a lot of Linux and VPS servers. When someone joins the company, other staff members need to add his SSH key to each server; conversely, if someone leaves, all of his SSH keys need to be removed. SSH keys are the primary issue, but the larger difficulty is that a person has many accounts on various organizational software applications (such as Git, Jira, etc.) and has his dashboard.

I would like to know whether there is a way to manage a user's account across all organizational platforms. Or at least about management of Linux users and their SSH keys?

I researched about SSO programs like KeyClock, but I can't find which one can solve our problem. If you have a suggestion about the exact problem, please write in answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Active directory to authenticate users across different platforms including linux. For linux one possible solution is to use sssd. Here is one [example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/pdf/configuring_authentication_and_authorization_in_rhel/red_hat_enterprise_linux-9-configuring_authentication_and_authorization_in_rhel-en-us.pdf) how to use it.

About storing keys you can use KeyCloak as it is described [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/store-user-ssh-keys-in-keycloak/11494/3).

> I’ve solved that by storing an attribute that is a JSON string. I
> don’t know if there is a better way to do it, as I don’t believe there
> is a list type.

Of course you can use [local LDAP](https://serverfault.com/a/653793/293588) which store user keys and expose them ssh.

> Update LDAP to include the OpenSSH-LPK schema
>
> We first need to update LDAP with a schema to add the sshPublicKey
> attribute for users:
> Create a script that queries LDAP for a user's
> public key:
> Update sshd_config to point to the script from the
> previous step

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will test it.