# ssh-certificate LDAP schema existence?

Tags: ssh, ldap, certificate, schema

**Hello.**
I'm looking for an *LDAP schema* to make it possible to publish my `ssh-certificates` into user/host *LDAP nodes*.
Is there any **common one**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH key authentication using LDAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/653792/ssh-key-authentication-using-ldap)